# Paper not mesh for really tight horizontal joints

Tags: drywall

Mesh tape, rather than paper, is typically used as joint compound reinforcement when the joint has no firm backing (structural lumber), most commonly horizontal lines that are perpendicular to the studs. It is easy to see why this reinforcement is necessary. But what if the crack/joint is so narrow/tight (like almost butted), can I just fill it with hot mud, as it is tight enough to stay without tape, and then paper tape over it just like I would vertical, backed joints?

Comment: Mesh tape can only be used with setting type mud. It's not for any particular joint conditions. It's nice because you don't have to butter the joint before applying the stuff. Hot mud is required for joints wider than 1/8" under ASTM C840 (paper or mesh tape are both fine). Tighter than 1/8" is great. Now you could also use paper tape and drying type mud without screwing anything up.

Comment: If you're using hot mud anyway, then just buy mesh tape and apply it before the hot mud.